# C++ pointers and memory leak

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I'd like to illustrate one thing I've seen:

```
class Something {};

void do_something(const Something *p_sth) {}
```

Then:

```
do_something(new Something());
```

should cause a memory leak because when you call **new** you should also always call **delete**, right? Would this be a good solution?

```
void do_something(const Something *p_sth)
{
    delete p_sth;
}
```

Or is it better to use references &? I also find out that smart pointers can solve this, so **delete** isn't required (it seems as a good thing but I have never used it before). I just want to know *what's the best solution* for this to avoid the memory leak. Thanks

*Thank you all for your answers. It helped me to clear up few things. I'm also sorry for the code I posted as it was maybe too general.

Comment: "should cause a memory leak ..." Impossible to tell without knowing what `do_something` does with its argument. In other words, don't `new` the argument unless the function documentation says that is what you should do.

Comment: There are many possible solutions as you've mentioned. The 'right' one depends on a specific application (where do you want to use it?, will it be used with inheritance?  and so on...)

Comment: Using smart pointers is superior, but yes, what you wrote won't cause memory leak because the function clean it up. You can only use references when it's impossible to get nullptr as a value... so it depends on the situation

Comment: As a side note: If you use smart pointers you shouldn't call nor new or delete, you can use make_unique and make_shared

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. With this example, you cannot use the passed pointer afterwards, which might cause some troubles... Why allocate on the heap, if you restrict its lifetime as if it was on the stack?

Comment: In modern C++ there's very few cases where you actually *need* pointers (polymorphism when you can't use references being one of them). And the new smart pointers introduced in C++11 should be seen more in terms of resource ownership instead of as simple auto-deleting pointers.

Comment: @LogicStuff: If it use this object polymorphically and it also take ownership it's make sense to don't use stack object... this is a minimal example, so this question is out of scope.

Comment: This question seems to me rather broad and opinion-based, which is unfortunately off-topic here...

Comment: It is better style that the one which creates is the one which destroys. Smart pointers solve that with a clear semantic to transfer ownership. So it is strange that `do_something` deletes `p_sth`.

Comment: Why use a pointer? It is much harder to leak with `void do_something(const Something& sth) {}`

Comment: all the above points being valid, you could accomplish having it auto-delete in C++11 by: `do_something( std::unique_ptr<Something>(new Something).get() );` and C++14 by `do_something( std::make_unique<Something>().get() );`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It helped me to clear up few things. I'm also sorry for the code I posted as it was maybe too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion of assuming the ownership of the pointer and deleting the object has problems.

That behaviour is not idiomatic in c++. Programmers expect that they must delete every object that they allocate with `new`. If a user of your function expects that they're responsible for deleting the object whose address they pass to the function, then your solution breaks apart. Also, it prevents using your function with objects that must keep existing after the call has ended:

```
Something* s = new s();
do_something(s);
s.foo() // oops, object was deleted, I can't use it anymore
delete s; // oops, double delete because I'm for some reason not responsible for deleting the object that I allocated
```

Your solution also prevents using automatically and statically allocated objects with the function.

```
Something s;
do_something(&s); //oops, do_something assumes that object is dynamically allocated
```

All of these caveats would have to be documented to the user of the function.

A raw pointer without deleting inside the function has none of these problems. Managing the callers memory should really not be the responsibility of your function. Doing that would break the single responsibility principle. There's nothing wrong with raw pointer parameters when you *don't* want to transfer or share ownership. If you do want to imply changes in ownership, then use smart pointers which were designed exactly for that.

Smart pointers don't have some of the above problems, but they still prevent using the function with automatic and static objects.

A reference parameter is in many cases ideal. It communicates the caller that they're still responsible for the object. As a bonus, The lack of need for addressof operator allows slightly nicer syntax. Sure, the caller may still forget to manage their memory, but as I pointed out, that shouldn't be your responsibility.

References have one potential drawback. They can't be null. If you don't need null, then it's actually an advantage.

Which solution is ideal, depends on what you need. Following is not true for all corner cases, but should hold for most common cases:

- If you want to modify the object, then pass a reference.

  - Unless you need null, in which case use a pointer
- If you just want to read the object, then

  - If the object is copyable, small (size less than or equal to word), doesn't cointain pointers to dynamic objects and not polymorphic, then pass by value
  - Otherwise or if you don't know those things because you're writing a template, pass a const reference
  - Unless you need null, in which case use a pointer
- If you want to If you want to transfer ownership, then use `unique_ptr`
- If you want that ownership to be shared, then use `shared_ptr`

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use a smart pointer

```
class Something {};

void do_something(std::shared_ptr<Something> p_sth) 
{
...
}
```

That way the ownership is clear when you look at the prototype as well as you get an automatic delete when you leave scope.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know what's the best solution for this to avoid the memory leak. Thanks

The best solution to ensure there are no memory leaks would be to use `std::shared_ptr`which is a smart pointer which, as soon as it does not have any references, deletes itself. This pointer is best if you have more than on reference to the same pointer. Use `std::unique_ptr` if there is only one reference at a given time.

This will prevent memory leaks and I also prefer using smart pointers rather than standard pointers as they are very powerful. Also, retaining to the question:

> Or is it better to use references &?

Use references wherever you need to reference the object, if you delete the reference, being a smart pointer, it will delete the pointer as well *(Being there are no other references to that pointer)*

I hope this answers your questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to avoid the use of raw pointers.

If you do not need a heap allocation and can use a stack allocated variable, then prefer to pass by reference (or even pass by value if an appropriate move constructor is in place, but that's a topic for another day).

If you need a heap allocation (for polymorphism, dependency injection, information hiding, transfer of ownership etc.) then determine what the ownership semantics will be for that object and use the appropriate smart pointer to manage those semantics.

If all else fails and you must use a raw pointer (perhaps you are dealing with a legacy interface or a C interface, or something similar) then again, clearly define your ownership semantics and document them to make it clear who is responsible for deleting the heap allocated object, etc.

If you must have a raw pointer to a stack allocated object then document that you will not be deleting the pointer and be careful about documenting the lifetime of the pointer to avoid accessing the object after it has gone out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest solution would be to avoid the pointer completely.
And yes, a reference is a good idea.

```
void do_something(const Something &p_sth) {}
```

Then you can declare your 'something' on the Stack.

```
void function_that_does_something()
{
    Something mySomething;

    do_something( mySomething );
}
```

It is always best to let the compiler do the cleanup for you.